# How to use knn classification (class package) using training and test datasets

Tags: r, classification, knn

`Dfcensus` is the original data frame. I am trying to use `Sex`, `EducYears` and `Age` to predict whether a person's `Income` is `"<=50K"` or `">50K"`.

There are 20,000 rows in `x_train_auto` (training set) and 12,561 in `x_test_auto` (test set).

My classification variable (training set) has 15,124 <=50k and 4876 >50k.

Here is my code:

```r
predictions = knn(train = x_train_auto, # response
                  test  = x_test_auto, # response
                  cl = Df_census$Income[in_train_census], # prediction
                  k = 25)

table(predictions)
#<=50K 
#12561
```

As you can see, all 12,561 test samples were predicted to have an `Income` of ">=50K".

This doesn't make sense. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

P.S.: I have sex one-hot encodes as 0 for male and 1 for female. And I have scaled Educ_years and Age and added sex to the data frame. I then added the one-hot encoded sex variable back into the scaled test and train data.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Sample input is here  - x test_auto.csv https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kupkp4u4qyizy7/x_test_auto.csv?dl=0                                                                                                  x_train_auto - https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kupkp4u4qyizy7/x_test_auto.csv?dl=0

Comment: and here   in_train_census https://www.dropbox.com/s/jnzpkzm0ss5f5tp/in_train_census.csv?dl=0                                                                                    Df_census  - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ccvck8ajnatmpv0/Df_census.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**identifying the problem**

Your provided `x_test-auto.csv` data suggests that you passed logical vectors with `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s (which define the *indices* of training and test samples rather than the actual data) to the `train` and `test` arguments of `class::knn`.

**the solution**

Rather, use the logical vector in `x_train_auto` (which I believe corresponds to `in_train_census` in your example) to define two separate `data.frame`s, each containing all your desired predictors. These are then the *training* and the *test* set.

```r
p <- c("Age","EducYears","Sex")
Df_train <- Df_census[in_train_census,p]
Df_test <- Df_census[!in_train_census,p]
```

In the `knn` function, pass the *training set* to the `train` argument, and the *test set* to the `test` argument, and further pass the outcome / target variable of the training set (as a factor) to `cl`.

The output (see `?class::knn`) will be the predicted outcome for the *test set*.

Here is a complete and reproducible workflow using your data.

**the data**

```r
library(class)

# read data from Dropbox
x_train_auto <- read.csv("https://dropbox.com/s/6kupkp4u4qyizy7/x_test_auto.csv?dl=1", row.names = 1)
Df_census <- read.csv("https://dropbox.com/s/ccvck8ajnatmpv0/Df_census.csv?dl=1", row.names = 1, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

table(x_train_auto) # TRUE are training, FALSE are test set
#> x_train_auto
#> FALSE  TRUE 
#> 12561 20000
str(Df_census) # Income as factor, Sex is binary, Age and EducYears are numeric
#> 'data.frame':    32561 obs. of  15 variables:
#>  $ Age          : int  39 50 38 53 28 37 49 52 31 42 ...
#>  $ Work         : Factor w/ 9 levels "?","Federal-gov",..: 8 7 5 5 5 5 5 7 5 5 ...
#>  $ Fnlwgt       : int  77516 83311 215646 234721 338409 284582 160187 209642 45781 159449 ...
#>  $ Education    : Factor w/ 16 levels "10th","11th",..: 10 10 12 2 10 13 7 12 13 10 ...
#>  $ EducYears    : int  13 13 9 7 13 14 5 9 14 13 ...
#>  $ MaritalStatus: Factor w/ 7 levels "Divorced","Married-AF-spouse",..: 5 3 1 3 3 3 4 3 5 3 ...
#>  $ Occupation   : Factor w/ 15 levels "?","Adm-clerical",..: 2 5 7 7 11 5 9 5 11 5 ...
#>  $ Relationship : Factor w/ 6 levels "Husband","Not-in-family",..: 2 1 2 1 6 6 2 1 2 1 ...
#>  $ Race         : Factor w/ 5 levels "Amer-Indian-Eskimo",..: 5 5 5 3 3 5 3 5 5 5 ...
#>  $ Sex          : int  1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 ...
#>  $ CapitalGain  : int  2174 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14084 5178 ...
#>  $ CapitalLoss  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#>  $ HoursPerWeek : int  40 13 40 40 40 40 16 45 50 40 ...
#>  $ NativeCountry: Factor w/ 42 levels "?","Cambodia",..: 40 40 40 40 6 40 24 40 40 40 ...
#>  $ Income       : Factor w/ 2 levels "<=50K",">50K": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...

# predictors and response
p <- c("Age","EducYears","Sex")
y <- "Income"

# create data partition
in_train_census <- x_train_auto$x

Df_train <- Df_census[in_train_census,]
Df_test <- Df_census[!in_train_census,]

# check
dim(Df_train)
#> [1] 20000    15

dim(Df_test)
#> [1] 12561    15

table(Df_train$Income)
#> 
#> <=50K  >50K 
#> 15124  4876
```

**using `class::knn`**

The `knn` (k-nearest-neighbors) algorithm can perform better or worse depending on the choice of the hyperparameter `k`. It's often difficult to know which `k` value is best for the classification of a particular dataset. In a machine learning setting, you'd want to try out different values of `k` to find a value that gives the highest performance on your *test dataset* (i.e., data which was not used for model fitting).

It's always important to strike a good balance between *overfitting* (model is too complex, and will give good results on the training data, but less accurate or even rubbish results on new test data) and *underfitting* (model is too trivial to explain the actual patterns in the data). In the case of `knn`, using a *larger k value* would probably better safeguard against overfitting, according to the explanations [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/knn-model-complexity/).

```r
# apply knn for various k using the given training / test set
r <- data.frame(array(NA, dim = c(0, 2), dimnames = list(NULL, c("k","accuracy"))))

for (k in 1:30) {
  
  #cat("k =", k, "\n")
  
  # fit model on training set, predict test set data
  set.seed(60402) # to be reproducible
  predictions <- knn(train = Df_train[,p],
                     test = Df_test[,p],
                     cl = Df_train[,y],
                     k = k)
  
  # confusion matrix on test set
  t <- table(pred = predictions, ref = Df_test[,y])
  
  # accuracy
  a <- sum(diag(t)) / sum(t)
  
  # bind
  r <- rbind(r, data.frame(k = k, accuracy = a))
}
```

**visualize model assessment**

```r
# find best k
r[which.max(r$accuracy),]
#>     k  accuracy
#> 17 17 0.8007324

(k.best <- r[which.max(r$accuracy),"k"])
#> [1] 17

# plot
with(r, plot(k, accuracy, type = "l"))
abline(v = k.best, lty = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**interpretation**

The loop results suggest that your **optimal** value of `k` *for this particular training and test set* is **between 12 and 17** (see plot above), but the accuracy gain is very small compared to using `k = 1` (it's at around *80%* regardless of `k`).

**additional thoughts**

Given that high income is rarer compared to lower income, accuracy might not be the desired performance metric. [Sensitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity#Sensitivity) might be equally or more important, and you could modify the example code to calculate and assess other performance metrics instead.

In addition to pure prediction, you might want to explore whether other variables could be informative predictors of the `Income` class, by adding them to the `p` vector and comparing the resulting accuracies.

Here, we base our conclusions on a particular realization of training and test data. Better machine learning practice would be to split your data into 2 (as here), but then repeatedly split the training set again to fit and assess many more models, using e.g. (repeated) [k-fold cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#k-fold_cross-validation). A good package to do this in R is e.g. [caret](https://topepo.github.io/caret/) or [tidymodels](https://www.tidymodels.org/start/).

To gain a better understanding regarding which variables are the best predictors of Income class, I would also carry out a *logistic regression* on various uncorrelated predictors.

Comment: Wow thank you for the answer and the thorough explanation. This is for a class and we are learning about cross-fold validation now. They are having us do it the long way first. I understand this problem so much better now.